# Assigning jQuery ajaxStart by a class selector and manipulating the result by an id selector

Tags: jquery

Suppose this is my html

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="photo"></div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="info" class="menu">Info</div>
    <div id="msg" class="menu">Message</div>
    <div id="files" class="menu">Files</div>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

I want to assign `$('.menu').ajaxStart()` so that all the `div` with the `class="menu"` are assigned the `ajaxStart()` and eventually the `ajaxStop()` jQuery events'

My problem is that I want to show some kind of progress (text or progress gif) when the ajax event is running but not on all the `div` with `class="menu"` but on the particular `id` that i have clicked on.  Lets say for instance I click on div with `id=info`the progress should be shown only on that `div`.

How can i achieve this?  Thanks in advance.

Example at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/68WMm/)

Comment: Are you looking [for this](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/hnnSH/) ?

Comment: @Raynos ah nope I know it can be done that way. I was just wondering why this is not working out.

Comment: It's "not working out" because that's just not how those "ajax" event handlers work.  You would have to have your "click" handler set up some sort of global (or relatively global) variable to track which element is involved, and then have the "ajax" handlers refer to that. That would be a weird way to do things. Also, it's important to note that the "ajaxStart" handler is only called if no other ajax request is currently pending.

Comment: @Pointy Ok I give up seems manually doing as you said in the respective click events has benefits and is better too...  my code doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do this with the "ajax" events; just do it in the "click" handler.

```
$('#info').click(function(){
    var $clicked = $(this);
    $clicked.text('Requesting...');
    $.post('/echo/html/', {
        html: '<div id="username">lonewolfs</div><div id="firstname">Lone</div><div id="lastname">WOLFs</div><div id="sex">1</div><div id="dob">1982-10-20</div><div id="address">Bahamas</div><div id="city">XYZ</div><div id="state">StateXYZ</div><div id="country">USA</div><div id="phone">9999999999</div><div id="email">lonewolfs.glory@gmail.com</div><div id="messagebody"></div>'
    }, function(data) {
        $('body').append($(data).filter('#email'));
        $clicked.text("Done...!");
    });
});
```

The "ajax" events can be useful for doing certain kinds of things, but in this case there's really no point, and it's just an added difficulty. The problem is that there's absolutely no intrinsic relationship between the real "click" event and the synthetic "ajaxStart" and "ajaxStop" events, so there's no way to know why the "ajaxStart" is happening. Since you've got a "click" handler anyway, and it *does* know the element involved, that's the best place to do the work.